# Parse.com sorted query result same order with the array given

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an array containing objectid's of the objects I want in a sorted matter. I want to get a query result of these objects which is in the exact same order with the array.

Query.whereContainedIn("objectId", mysortedarray)

Doesn't give me the sorted results. How can I accomplish this?

The only way I can think of is order them after getting the results but is there a way to get them ordered while query?

Comment: If the Parse object doesn't contain the data you are sorting on then you will need to sort the objects after you retrieve them - Or perhaps  you could use a cloud code function that you send the objectids to and have it retrieve and sort the data on the Parse side before returning the data

Comment: I didn't exactly get the cloud code part. Could you explain a little more detailed.

Comment: You can write a CloudCode function in Javascript - it executes on the Parse server.  You could invoke this function from your app instead of `query` - pass in the ordered list of IDs and get back the objects in the right order - it is doing the same thing you would do to sort the results in your app but on the server side

Answer (score 0):

There is addAscendingOrder and  addDescendingOrder in ParseQuery class try that.

[ParseQuery](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html)

Check method section in it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't think this would work because the order of the results has to be the same order of the IDs given in the array.